# How to ignore non digits in a foor loop in Python?

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop, filter

I have a list named, `new_to_csv`, which looks like this:

```
    [['88', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 06:05:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:03:00+00:00'],
    ['*021', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:26:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:34:01+00:00'],` 
    ['*023', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:30:00+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:50:18+00:00'],   `
    ['nodigit', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 03:00:03+00:00', '2020-09-07 23:30:01+00:00'],
    ['++158', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:42:05+00:00', '2020-09-07 10:02:01+00:00'],`       
    ['200', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:08:32+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:05:00+00:00']]
```

I also have a file named, `table_x,` which looks like this:

```
XXXXXX  Version 1.0 BATOS DE ESPANA                                                                             
11-12-2011 t/m 08-12-2012                                                       
RG  Mini    Maxi    Organization    ISVL    PR  BSS Afw     Rage    TrT Trajecto    IBB Ant Dato    
*****data*****                                                      
R   1   99  BALEARIA    BALEARIA        Gers  INT       INT C       IB  99      
R   100 103 Espanola                    NIG             4       
R   104 105 BALEARIA    BALEARIA            PC  ICE C   Asd - Ut - Ah - Espana  IB  2       
R   106 119 Espanola                    NIG             14      
R   120 129 BALEARIA    BALEARIA            PC  ICE C   Asd - Ut - Ah - Barcelona - Almeria IB  10      
R   130 139 Espanola                    NIG             10      
R   140 149 BALEARIA    BALEARIA            PC  INT C   Shl - Amf - Dv - Hgl - Bh - Algeciras   IB  10      
R   150 159 BALEARIA    BALEARIA        SVS ICE PC  ICE C   Asd - Ut - Vl - Barcelona - Almeria IB  10      
R   160 219 BALEARIA    BALEARIA        Gere  INT   PC  INT C       IB  60      
R   220 229 BALEARIA    BALEARIA            PC  ICE C   Asd - Ut - Ah - Barcelona - Almeria IB  10
```

Now for every `x[0]` in `new_to_csv` I'am first checking if its a digit or not. If it is a digit Iam checking between between what `mini` and `maxi` it occurs. I grab the columns `3:8` of the row it occurs in and paste it behind that list. If `x[0]` is not a digit I skip it and write 'Unkown' as output.

**This is my code:**

```
table_x = r"C:\Users\ELK\Downloads\table_x.txt"

result_list = []
with open(table_x, "r") as outer:
    reader = csv.reader(outer, delimiter="\t")
    next(reader) #skip the first 4 lines
    next(reader)
    next(reader)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        mini = row[1]  
        maxi = row[2]  
        for x in new_to_csv:
            veh_number = x[0]
            check_digit = veh_number.isdigit()
            if check_digit:   #<--- check if its digit
                if int(veh_number) > int(mini) and int(veh_number) < int(maxi):
                    result_list.append(x+ [row[3]]+ [row[4]]+ [row[5]]+ [row[6]]+ [row[7]]+ [row[8]])
            if check_digit is False: #if its not digit
                result_list.append(x + [row[3]] + [row[4]] + [row[5]] + ["Unkown"])

print(result_list)
```

**This is the output I expected:**

```
[['88', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 06:05:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:03:00+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Gers  INT', '', 'INT'], 
['*021', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:26:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:34:01+00:00','Unkown', 'Unkown', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*023', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:30:00+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:50:18+00:00', 'Unkown', 'Unkown', '', 'Unkown'], 
['nodigit', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 03:00:03+00:00','2020-09-07 23:30:01+00:00', 'Unkown', 'Unkown', '', 'Unkown'], 
['++158', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:42:05+00:00', '2020-09-07 10:02:01+00:00', 'Unkown', 'Unkown', '', 'Unkown'],
['200', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:08:32+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:05:00+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Gere  INT', 'PC', 'INT']]
```

Above you see the output I expected. `88` is a digit and is between `1` and `99` so I grab the columns `3:8` from that row. `*021` is not a digit so I write `'Unknown'` etc..

Now below you see the output I received, it seems to do the non-digits multiple times. I dont understand why...

**This is the output I received:**

```
[['88', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 06:05:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:03:00+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Gers  INT', '', 'INT'], 
['*021', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:26:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:34:01+00:00','BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*023', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:30:00+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:50:18+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['nodigit', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 03:00:03+00:00','2020-09-07 23:30:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['++158', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:42:05+00:00', '2020-09-07 10:02:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'],
['*021', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:26:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:34:01+00:00', 'Espanola', '', '', 'Unkown'],
['*023', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:30:00+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:50:18+00:00', 'Espanola', '', '', 'Unkown'], 
['nodigit', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 03:00:03+00:00', '2020-09-07 23:30:01+00:00', 'Espanola', '', '', 'Unkown'], 
['++158', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:42:05+00:00', '2020-09-07 10:02:01+00:00', 'Espanola', '', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*021', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:26:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:34:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*023', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:30:00+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:50:18+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'],
 ['nodigit', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 03:00:03+00:00', '2020-09-07 23:30:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'],
 ['++158', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:42:05+00:00', '2020-09-07 10:02:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*021', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:26:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:34:01+00:00', 'Espanola', '', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*023', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:30:00+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:50:18+00:00', 'Espanola', '', '', 'Unkown'],
 ['nodigit', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 03:00:03+00:00', '2020-09-07 23:30:01+00:00', 'Espanola', '', '', 'Unkown'], 
['++158', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:42:05+00:00', '2020-09-07 10:02:01+00:00', 'Espanola', '', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*021', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:26:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:34:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*023', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:30:00+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:50:18+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['nodigit', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 03:00:03+00:00', '2020-09-07 23:30:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['++158', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:42:05+00:00', '2020-09-07 10:02:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*021', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:26:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:34:01+00:00', 'Espanola', '', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*023', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:30:00+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:50:18+00:00', 'Espanola', '', '', 'Unkown'], 
['nodigit', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 03:00:03+00:00', '2020-09-07 23:30:01+00:00', 'Espanola', '', '', 'Unkown'], 
['++158', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:42:05+00:00', '2020-09-07 10:02:01+00:00', 'Espanola', '', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*021', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:26:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:34:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'],
['*023', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:30:00+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:50:18+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'],
[ 'nodigit', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 03:00:03+00:00', '2020-09-07 23:30:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['++158', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:42:05+00:00', '2020-09-07 10:02:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*021', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:26:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:34:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'],
['*023', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:30:00+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:50:18+00:00', 'BALEARIA','BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['nodigit', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 03:00:03+00:00', '2020-09-07 23:30:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'],
['++158', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:42:05+00:00', '2020-09-07 10:02:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*021', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:26:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:34:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'],
['*023', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:30:00+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:50:18+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'],
['nodigit', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 03:00:03+00:00', '2020-09-07 23:30:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['++158', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:42:05+00:00', '2020-09-07 10:02:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'],
['200', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:08:32+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:05:00+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Gere  INT', 'PC', 'INT'], 
['*021', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:26:07+00:00', '2020-09-07 09:34:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['*023', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 08:30:00+00:00', '2020-09-07 13:50:18+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['nodigit', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 03:00:03+00:00', '2020-09-07 23:30:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown'], 
['++158', 'BRC', 'LON', '2020-09-07 05:42:05+00:00', '2020-09-07 10:02:01+00:00', 'BALEARIA', 'BALEARIA', '', 'Unkown']]
```

Comment: Why is there `'Unkown', 'Unkown', '', 'Unkown'` in your expected output, and not a single 'Unknown' nor the same amount of 'Unknown' as the number of fields for columns 3:8?

Comment: @00 I really dont know.. what do you mean?

Comment: You should read table_x separately (in a loop), store the results in a variable (which is probably a dict or similar), then *separately* iterate over new_to_csv. Now you're iterating over new_to_csv *inside* your iteration over table_x. That will not work as is.

Comment: @00 But why is it going well for the digits? The problem seems to occur only for the non digits.

Comment: I mean, you state "If x[0] is not a digit I skip it and write 'Unkown' as output.". Yet the expected output for which the first column is not a digit, have 3 times 'Unknown' plus an empty string; not a single 'Unknown' as per that sentence.

Comment: Well I meant to write 3 times unkown

Comment: Your code only shows `+ ['Unknown']` once.

Comment: @00 Yes I have to change that, but thats not where the problem arises. It seems to iterate several times over the non digits... I really have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your line to it.

```
if check_digit is False: #if its not digit
      result_list.append(x + ["Unkown"] + ["Unkown"] + [""] + ["Unkown"])
```

You were adding [row[3]] + [row[4]] + [row[5]] to x

***** FULL CODE *****

```
table_x = r"table_x.txt"

result_list = []
with open(table_x, "r") as outer:
    reader = csv.reader(outer, delimiter="\t")
    next(reader) #skip the first 4 lines
    next(reader)
    next(reader)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        mini = row[1]  
        maxi = row[2]


        for x in new_to_csv:
            veh_number = x[0]
            check_digit = veh_number.isdigit()
            if check_digit:   #<--- check if its digit
                if int(veh_number) > int(mini) and int(veh_number) < int(maxi):
                    result_list.append(x+ [row[3]]+ [row[4]]+ [row[5]]+ [row[6]]+ [row[7]]+ [row[8]])

    for x in new_to_csv:
        veh_number = x[0]
        check_digit = veh_number.isdigit()
        if check_digit is False: #if its not digit
            result_list.append(x + ["Unkown"] + ["Unkown"] + [""] + ["Unkown"])
print(result_list)
```

Comment: done that but I still get a lot of double non digits inside my list

Comment: can you share the result list?

Comment: I cant share it in here because its too big.

Comment: The problem is that you append it inside 2 loops, one for list and one for txt file. Each time in list loop, you append result_list.append(x + ["Unkown"] + ["Unkown"] + [""] + ["Unkown"]). So if you txt file has 10 main rows, and in your list you have 10 rows, it means, your final list will end with 10*10 rows = 100 rows.

Comment: So how can I solve this problem? Help your brother out akhi :)

Comment: I suggest you to append only digit in this loop. Then add only nondigits, as you dont need txt file for appending nondigits. Or viceversa, first append nondigits, then go through txt file and find min max values

Comment: Thank you men. Really helpfull.